# Can't figure out the end of these methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, rspec, syntax-error

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and I'm on chapter 8 of the rails tutorial. I'm getting a syntax error unexpected $end, expecting kEND. I know that means that I'm missing an end somewhere, but in both files i can't seem to figure it out. Here are both of my files. Thank you in advance for any help

user_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User, :type => :request do

  before do
    @user = User.new(:name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end


  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

 describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com foo@bar..com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        expect(@user).not_to be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "email address with mixed case" do
    let(:mixed_case_email) { "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM" }

    it "should be saved as all lower-case" do
      @user.email = mixed_case_email
      @user.save
      expect(@user.reload.email).to eq mixed_case_email.downcase
    end
  end

  describe "when password is not present" do
    before do
      @user = User.new(:name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com",
                       :password => " ", :password_confirmation => " ")
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email @user.email }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
    end

    describe "remember token" do
    before { @user.save }
    its(:remember_token) { should_not be_blank }
  end
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token
  validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, :presence =>   true,
                    :format =>    { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
  validates :password, :length => { :minimum => 6 }

  private

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.hex.urlsafe_base64
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending method seems to be

```
    describe "remember token" do
    before { @user.save }
    its(:remember_token) { should_not be_blank }
```

change to

```
    describe "remember token" do
      before { @user.save }
      its(:remember_token) { should_not be_blank }
    end
```

Comment: I already have: describe "remember token" do
    before { @user.save }
    its(:remember_token) { should_not be_blank }
  end
end
deleting or adding an extra end here still gives the error

Comment: Your `user_spec.rb` should end with 3 `end` keywords.